# FFMPEG - Crop image so that height and width of image are equal

Tags: ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg, I want to be able to crop an image so that the dimensions become equal. For example if I have an input image that is 1600x1000, after cropping it should be 1000x1000 (because 1000 is the smallest amongst the two dimensions). When cropping the image, it should crop equally from both sides.

Some examples:
Input image: 1600x1000 -> crop 300px from the left and 300px from the right side. Final image 1000x1000.

Input image: 1100x1500 -> crop 200px from the top and 300px from the bottom. Final image 1100x1100.

I can use this the command below to crop left and right or bottom and top or both. But the problem is that I want to crop only the largest dimension. Is there any way to know the largest dimension?

```
crop=in_w-in_h/2:in_h-in_w/2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ffmpeg expression evaluation has a `min` function which you can use to make things pretty easy:

```
crop=min(in_w\,in_h):out_w
```

The output height is allowed to refer to the output width, which saves repeating the expression, and the x and y offsets default to `(in_w-out_w)/2` and `(in_h-out_h)/2` respectively so you get centering (equal cropping) by default if you don't specify anything